# How to combine two objects in an ee.List() Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, list, combine

I have this type of list in Google Earth Engine:

```
var list = ee.List([[{'class': 1, 'sum': 27188.96}, {'code': 'Cloud'}], 
                    [{'class': 2, 'sum': 1190.15}, {'code': 'Soil'}]])
```

and want to combine the objects whithin each lists, like this:

```
var list = ee.List([{'class': 1, 'sum': 27188.96, 'code': 'Cloud'},
                    {'class': 2, 'sum': 1190.15, 'code': 'Soil'}])
```

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map a function over the list of lists that, for each list, fetches the two dictionaries and then combines them:

```js
var list = ee.List([
  [{'class': 1, 'sum': 27188.969311237335}, {'code': 'Cloud'}],
  [{'class': 2, 'sum': 1190.1564819812775}, {'code': 'Soil'}]
]);

var newList = list.map(function(e) {
  var dict1 = ee.Dictionary(ee.List(e).get(0));
  var dict2 = ee.Dictionary(ee.List(e).get(1));
  return dict1.combine(dict2);
});

print(newList);
```